# Forward Geocoding

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

I am creating a simple map app. So far, I implemented my map view, as well as my search bar. I also played around with a forward geocoder I found at http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/, which is working great. But it appears since iOS 5, forward geocoding is a built-in feature. How exactly do I use this? The apple documentation is very short and not helpful.

I would like the user to input an address in a textfield or search bar and then display the coordinates on the map with an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Forward geocoding (iOS 5):

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
CLGeocoder* gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[gc geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) 
{
    if ([placemarks count]>0) 
    {
        // get the first one
        CLPlacemark* mark = (CLPlacemark*)[placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        double lat = mark.location.coordinate.latitude;
        double lng = mark.location.coordinate.longitude;            
    }
}];
```

Reverse geocoding (iOS 5):

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
CLGeocoder* gcrev = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[gcrev reverseGeocodeLocation:c completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) 
{
    CLPlacemark* revMark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    // turn placemark to address text
    NSArray* addressLines = [revMark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
    NSString* revAddress = [addressLines componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];
    // print
    NSLog(@"rev: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reverse geocoded address: \n%@", revAddress]);        
}];
```

CLPlacemark has quite a few properties:

- name
- addressDictionary: Address Book keys and values for the placemark.
- ISOcountryCode
- country
- postalCode
- administrativeArea
- subAdministrativeArea
- locality
- subLocality
- thoroughfare: Street address.
- subThoroughfare: Address Book keys and values for the placemark.
- region
- inlandWater
- ocean
- areasOfInterest

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 now allows for forward Geocoding:

Have a look here:

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW5)